# Dynamic UNION ALL query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, union-all

We are using a Postgres / PostGis connection to get data that is published via a geoserver.

The Query looks like this at the moment:

```
SELECT 
    row_number() over (ORDER BY a.ogc_fid) AS qid, a.wkb_geometry AS geometry
FROM
(
   SELECT * FROM test
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM test1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM test2
)a
```

In our db only valid shapefiles will be imported each in a single table so it would make sense to make the UNION ALL part dynamic (loop over each table and make the UNION ALL statement). Is there a way to do this in a standard Postgres way or do I need to write a function and how would the syntax look like? I am pretty new to SQL.

The shapefiles have a different data structure and only the ogc_fid column and the wkb_geometry column are always available and we would like to union all tables from the DB.

Comment: I don't really know what this shapefile thing is, but why don't you just import everything into a single table? Another option would be to use table inheritance

Comment: Your question isnt really clear. So the answer depend on what you want to do. But the easy solve is create a [**DYNAMIC QUERY**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ecpg-dynamic.html) but you need a way to know what are the tables you want to join

Comment: in shapefiles you can store geodata. We woud like to avoid storing everything in a single table because the data structure of the geodata can be different and we would like to keep all of the columns of each files for other queries

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I updated my question. In this particular DB all tables need to be Unioned

Comment: If you want to have different columns in each table, then you can't possibly use them in a union statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just general guidelines you need work in the details specially syntaxis.

You need create a store procedure

Create a loop checking `information_schema.tables` filter for the tablenames you want

```
DECLARE    
    rec record;
    strSQL text;
BEGIN
```

Then create a strSQL with each table

```
 FOR rec IN SELECT table_schema, table_name
            FROM information_schema.tables                
 LOOP
     strSQL := strSQL || 'SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM ' || 
               rec.table_schema || '.' || rec.table_name || ' UNION ';
 END LOOP;

-- have to remove the last ' UNION ' from strSQL    

strSQL := 'SELECT  row_number() over (ORDER BY a.ogc_fid) AS qid,
         a.wkb_geometry AS geometry FROM (' || strSQL || ')';

EXECUTE strSQL;
```

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto What make you think this is SQL Server?

Comment: thank you for your answer - that helped a lot. I ended up using UNION ALL. btw. I think there is a small mistake: it should be "rec.table_name || " instead of "rec.table_name + "

Comment: You are right, sometimes I mix sql server and postgres syntaxis.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am trying to use your solution and I am getting a syntax error at or near record.. any ideas?

Comment: Removing the last UNION from the string could work this way `strSQL := left(strSQL, -6);`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to serialize the rest of the columns to [json](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) with [row_to_json()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-json.html). (available since PostgreSQL9.2).
For PG9.1 (and earlier) you can use [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html), but note that all values are cast to text.

Why serialize? It is not possible to [union](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html) rows where the number of colums vary, or the datatypes do not match between the union queries.

I created a quick example to illustrate:

```
--DROP SCHEMA testschema CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA testschema;

CREATE TABLE testschema.test1 (
    id integer,
    fid integer,
    metadata text
);

CREATE TABLE testschema.test2 (
    id integer,
    fid integer,
    city text,
    count integer
);

CREATE TABLE testschema.test3 (
    id integer,
    fid integer
);


INSERT INTO testschema.test1 VALUES (1,   4450, 'lala');
INSERT INTO testschema.test2 VALUES (33,  6682, 'London', 12345);
INSERT INTO testschema.test3 VALUES (185, 8991);


SELECT 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.fid) AS qid, a.*
FROM
(
    SELECT id, fid, row_to_json(t.*) AS jsondoc FROM testschema.test1 t
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT id, fid, row_to_json(t.*) AS jsondoc FROM testschema.test2 t
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT id, fid, row_to_json(t.*) AS jsondoc FROM testschema.test3 t    
) a
```

SELECT output:

```
qid  id    fid    jsondoc
1;   1;    4450;  "{"id":1,"fid":4450,"metadata":"lala"}"
2;   33;   6682;  "{"id":33,"fid":6682,"city":"London","count":12345}"
3;   185;  8991;  "{"id":185,"fid":8991}"
```