# Union multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

I tried to follow this answer

[Dynamic UNION ALL query in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486057/dynamic-union-all-query-in-postgres)

but I am getting 
 **ERROR: syntax error at or near "record"**

```
DECLARE
    rec record;
    strSQL text; 
BEGIN
    FOR
        rec in 
                select table_name
                from 
                    information_schema.tables
                where
                    table_name like 'history%' 

        loop
                strSQL : = strSQL || 'Select * from' || rec.table_schema ||'.'|| rec.table_name || ' UNION '; 
        end loop; 
 -- remove last ' UNION ' from strSQL  

--strSQL := 'Select row_number() over(order by rowid ) as row_num from (' || strSQL || ')';



execute strSQL;
```

anyone have any ideas?

background:
history table is moved every night to its own table with the date appended.

so history04242018 for each table name, any better way to get the data for multiple days?

edit: tables will always have the same amount of columns so the union should be fine

edit2: I only have read access.

update 
with the suggestion of using an anonymous code block I am now using the following:

```
DO   
    $$
declare
  strSQL text;
begin
  select
    string_agg(format('select * from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), E' union\n')
    into strSQL
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_name like 'history%';


   execute strSQL ;
end $$;
```

however I now get the error

> Describe Error: Failed to retrieve EXPLAIN plan(s): ERROR: syntax
>   error at or near "DO"   Position: 58
>
> 0 record(s) affected

Comment: Here is how to build your dynamic statement using single query: `select string_agg(format('select * from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), E' union\n') into strSQL from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'history%';`

Comment: And about error: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

Comment: @Abelisto I can get the first part without the "into" working - not really sure what im supposed to do with the rest.

Comment: Second line in my answer `You need create a store procedure`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza read only environment

Comment: It is strange error. I suppose that the framework you are using to access DB tries to modify statements in some way.

Answer (score 3):

`declare`, `for`, `loop`, `execute` are the parts of the [`plpgsql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html), not plain `sql` (`declare` could be used in the plain `sql` but in different meaning). So you should to wrap your code into [anonymous block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) or into [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) if you want to return some data from it:

```
create function get_history(p_day int)
  returns table (<structure of history tables here>)
  -- or
  -- returns setof <history table name>
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  strSQL text;
begin
  select
    string_agg(format('select * from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), E' union\n')
    into strSQL
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_name like to_char(p_day, '"history__"FM09%');

  return query execute strSQL;
end $$;
```

Also look at the [Table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-partitioning.html) (choose your PostgreSQL version at the top of article).

---

**Update**

However there are several ways to return query data from anonymous plpgsql block without changing DB schema: [cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) and [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html).

IMO second one is simpler a bit, so:

```
do $$
declare
  strSQL text;
begin
  select
    string_agg(format('select * from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), E' union\n')
    into strSQL
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_name like to_char(p_day, '"history__"FM09%');

  -- Prepend "prepare", change the "foo" name as you wish
  strSQL := 'prepare foo as ' || strSQL;

  execute strSQL;
end $$;

-- Usage
execute foo;

-- And deallocate prepared statement when it does not need anymore:
deallocate foo;
```

[Simple working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8a99ec73b5bb271a0f5bd85e0d427800)

Comment: thanks for this, I however only have read only and cannot make functions.

Comment: updated the original question - still getting an error

Comment: @lookslikeanevo Answer updated for read only environment. See [Simple working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8a99ec73b5bb271a0f5bd85e0d427800)

Comment: Abellisto - same error as my update - even tried the sample from sqlfiddle and same error

Comment: @lookslikeanevo As I said in the last comment under the question: it seems that it is problem of the framework. As you can see it works on pure DB connection. So be more specific: what do you using to connect to DB and execute queries?

Comment: using aqua data studio, also tried to pgadmin 4 and same error

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.4.15 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit"

Comment: and PostgreSQL 9.1.18 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4), 64-bit

Comment: @lookslikeanevo Ok, we came from your original question to the problems with `DO` block. Try to start with something simplest, like `do $$ begin raise notice 'Hello, World!'; end $$;` [(screenshot)](http://i6.imageban.ru/out/2018/04/26/35db476484b471149eb4e859e607215e.png). Also try to use native PostgreSQL tool [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for testing purpose. If this simplest example does not works for you - you should ask another question about it (IMO).

Comment: I get the same error - I will have to work through that first